# Как реализовать автоматический перезапуск интерфейса в PyQT5 при ошибке?

Tags: python, pyqt5, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyqt

Есть фронт с кнопками написанный на QtWidgets , который управляет эмуляцией браузера через Selenium. Иногда происходит непонятный баг, который закрывает интерфейс, но оставляет открытыми вкладки браузера. Как реализовать автоматический перезапуск только интерфейса, в случае его крэша, сохраняя то что открыто в браузере?

Упрощенный код бэка, дабы была понятна его структура:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from interface import Ui_MainWindow
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.google.com/"
driver.get(url) 

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):  #связываем функции с UI кнопками
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.NoAdress)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.SpecTransp)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.NoSvetofor)

    def NoAdress(self):          #функция для кнопки 1
        driver.execute_script('''some js code 1''')

    def SpecTransp(self): #функция для кнопки 2
        driver.execute_script('''some js code 2''')

    def NoSvetofor(self): #функция для кнопки 3
        driver.execute_script('''some js code 3''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Может, стоит устранить причины, по которым падает `gui`?

Comment: Это конечно да, но сейчас горит дедлайн и надо хотя бы так проблему закрыть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы использовал такой паттерн:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from interface import Ui_MainWindow
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import os
import sys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.google.com/"
driver.get(url) 

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):  #связываем функции с UI кнопками
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.NoAdress)


    def NoAdress(self):
        try:
            driver.execute_script('''some js code 1''')
        except:
            self.restart()

    def restart(self):

        os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)



    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```